# Javascript compare two arrays of variable length and show if there's common elment(s)

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

I want to compare two arrays of different length and if there's a common element between them show an alert or dosomething.

```
var valuesAdded= ["ab","c","d","eeef","bbc","ac","jk","df","ss"]
var valuesToadd= ["aaa","jk","eeef","ddd","d","ab","rs"]
```

so either valuesAdded can be larger or valuesToadd can be larger, but what i want is compare them for those element that already exists in the above case "eeef","d","jk","ab" and show an alert that these are already in valuesAdded etc.

I would like to do in regular javascript or usingdojo.

Can you please help in this regards, your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nothing really Javascript specific here:

```
for(var i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
        if(arr1[i] === arr2[j]){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i updated the question with more meaningful array names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me try it and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers you can do

```
valuesToAdd.forEach(){function(a){
  valuesAdded.indexOf+1?valuesAdded.push(a):alert('You already have this item');
}};
```

For older browser less than IE9 you would have to fall back to the other methods presented here.